# When people install my app, they get two apps

Tags: android, kotlin

When people install my app, they get two apps (same app, two icons). Here's my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".HistoryActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PaymentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PlayerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity android:name=".VideoActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FacebookActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LibraryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BookDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BookActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CategoryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TextActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <service android:name="com.beraldo.playerlib.PlayerService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".LaunchPlayerBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.beraldo.playerlib.LAUNCH_PLAYER_ACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Here's my AndroidManifest.xml file" -- that is *part* of your manifest file. Please post the entire `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Possible reason. may be you have more than one  LAUNCHER activity.

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>    This instruction might be availabe more than one time.

Comment: Android cannot install two app with the same `ApplicationId` A.K.A `packageName`. Maybe you have two `Launcher` activities or you installed the `debug` and `release` build-types on the same phone.

Comment: I updated the question with my full androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and you have:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Both have the `<intent-filter>` that says you want those activities to have icons in the launcher. If that is not what you want, remove the `<intent-filter>` from one of them.

Comment: if I remove the intent-filter on splash activity I get a blank screen when I load the app and then the app. How do I add a splash screen to the app?

Comment: @LouisaScheinost: If you want a splash activity, and the splash activity starts your main activity, remove the `<intent-filter>` from the main activity and keep it on the splash activity.